# How to decrypt a value from file, encrypted using Fernet

Tags: python, encryption, fernet

I am working on decrypting a password reading from a table which was decrypted manually using the `cryptography.fernet` class in Python

manually encrypting the password :

````
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
eencrypted_passwd = f.encrypt("password".encode('utf-8'))```
````

output :

```
b'gAAAAABeiTIiONj5c2Tyj1xDaoCLfK9_RJEqzdnuJyw_JO3AduywKhygNFYk1_a_srEgNvHB__vpcL-CElWROExQnwJHaydAmQ=='
```

the output value was stored in a table.

I am trying to decrypt the same value after reading from table but I am getting a blank error :

```
decrypted_password = f.decrypt(password_encrypted_value_read_from_database)
```

can someone please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take care of above by using jasypt4py library from git : https://github.com/fareliner/jasypt4py